# Electric potential due to surface charge distribution on a conducting sphere

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

Let's consider a conducting sphere. If we charge the sphere, it is understood that there will form a surface charge distribution such that the surface of the sphere is an equipotential surface
$ 0=\int_s \sigma(s)\frac{1}{|p-q(s)|}\,\mathrm{d}s $
where leads the same result given by Gauss's law.

This is saying that the potential at any point on the surface feels the contribution from the rest of charges.

My question is why would the potential at north pole feel the contribution from the surface charge at south pole? The way we compute the above integral is to treat as if there is no conductor. However there is a conducting sphere in between these two locations. Why is this calculation still valid?